# Missing value didnt disappear

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I tried to replace the missing value with 0, but it didn't work. Here is my code :

```
df_all_data[[ 'Temps_normal_trajet_agent', 'Temps_astreinte_trajet_agent',  
  'Heures_suptrajet_agent','Duree_normale_intervention_agent', 
  'Duree_intervention_astreinte_agent' , 'Duree_intervention_Heures_supagent' , 
  'FDROUTE_DATE' ]].fillna(0)
```

And here is the result I got:
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide us an example that we can replicate? It is hard to see where the problem is.

Comment: i have shared my exemple, i have dataframe with missing value and i apply fillna(0) to replace all missing value with 0 but it doesnt work and i dont know why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember to reassign to the original variable. `fillna` by default is not an inplace operation.  You can also use, `inplace=True` as an argument to fillna.  For example, .fillna(0, inplace=True) then you don't reassign.

```
df_all_data[[ 'Temps_normal_trajet_agent', 'Temps_astreinte_trajet_agent',
'Heures_suptrajet_agent','Duree_normale_intervention_agent', 'Duree_intervention_astreinte_agent' , 'Duree_intervention_Heures_supagent' , 'FDROUTE_DATE' ]] = df_all_data[[ 'Temps_normal_trajet_agent', 'Temps_astreinte_trajet_agent',
'Heures_suptrajet_agent','Duree_normale_intervention_agent', 'Duree_intervention_astreinte_agent' , 'Duree_intervention_Heures_supagent' , 'FDROUTE_DATE' ]].fillna(0)
```

Comment: i lost other columns that dont have nan value :/

Comment: @aminebak See edit... you can use inplace but don't reassign back to a variable. Or you can reassign back to the columns.